# Bounding function using non-positive derivative at bound

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Consider a function $f : \mathcal{R} \rightarrow \mathcal{R}$. Suppose that

- $f(0) \leq 0$
- $\forall x \in \{y : \mathcal{R}~|~y \geq 0~\wedge~f(y) = 0\},~f'(x) \leq 0$

Prove that $\forall x \geq 0, f(x) \leq 0$.

Informally, I want to prove that $f$ stays non-positive if it starts non-positive and has non-positive derivative wherever it hits zero.

How can I prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function

$$
f(x) = e^{-\frac1{x^2}} \quad \text{for}\  x \neq 0; \qquad f(x) = 0 \quad \text{for}\  x=0.
$$

This function is continuous for every real value. In fact

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} e^{-\frac1{x^2}} =e^{-\infty} = 0.
$$

It is also derivable for every real number.

$$
f'(x) = \frac2{x^3} e^{-\frac1{x^2}} \qquad \text{for}\  x \neq 0,
$$

and the derivative in zero is, by definition

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac {e^{-\frac1{x^2}} - 0}{x-0} =\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac1x {e^{-\frac1{x^2}}} = \lim_{t\rightarrow \pm \infty} t {e^{-t^2}}=0.
$$

In fact, it can be shown that $\ f(x) \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb R)$.

So $\ f(0)= f'(0)= 0 \ $ (in fact $\ f^{(n)}(0)= 0 \quad \forall n $)$\ $  but
$f(x)> 0 \ $ for $x>0$. So, your claim does not hold. Maybe it could work if you suppose that $\ f'(y) < 0.$

Comment: I don't think that function satisfies all of the premises. The derivative of your function is 0 at x=0. For the function in my question, the derivative is zero at all values of x where f(x)=0.

Comment: My $f(x)=0$ only for $x=0,$ so it holds. It is always positive for $x\neq 0.$

Comment: And, however, I may also consider a function like $g(x) = e^{-\frac1{x^2}}\cdot e^{-\frac1{(x-1)^2}}\  $ and this hits zero also for $\ x=1,\ $ but its derivative is zero also there.

Comment: Ah I see now. Thanks for the clarification. I was trying to post a simplified version of theorem 1 from this paper: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~jadbabai/papers/hscc04_2.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjA9_79_d3QAhXprFQKHZsqBHEQFghNMAM&usg=AFQjCNFlzYJUqFEVfrQi7reU04PicIUyww&sig2=WKCSkBZO4ee9AbfOxluqoQ. I guess I missed something, or that theorem is wrong.

Comment: I tried to read the paper, but it's not easy to see the points. However, my $f$ is not analytic, so, maybe, if in control theory they just use polynomials or power series, my function does not pop up.

Comment: The paper is quite hard to read. However, can't you use $f(x)=x^2$ as a counter example? This is an analytic function that I would expect to show up in control theory.

Comment: You are right. Maybe ask for $f'(y) <0$? I don't know, one should ask the authors...